# Change background color of a shape in a grid

Tags: swiftui, gridview

I made a grid using LazyGrid and I want to change individual item background color when it tapped based on its current selection status in the data model.

I tried to use onTapGesture()
it doesn't reload the grid and update the background color

```swift
class Day: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let value: Int
    var isSelected: Bool
    
    init(value: Int, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.value = value
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var days = [
        Day(value: 1, isSelected: true),
        Day(value: 2, isSelected: false),
        Day(value: 3, isSelected: false),
        Day(value: 4, isSelected: true)
    ]
    
    let layout = [
           GridItem(.fixed(40)),
           GridItem(.fixed(40)),
           GridItem(.fixed(40)),
           GridItem(.fixed(40))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: layout) {
                ForEach(days) { day in
                    Capsule()
                        .overlay(Text("\(day.value)").foregroundColor(.white))
                        .foregroundColor(day.isSelected ? .blue : .red)
                        .frame(height: 40)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            days[0].isSelected.toggle()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change Day to a struct

Comment: As suggested by *lorem ipsum*, an easy solution is to change `Day` to a `struct`. You also need to make it `@State private var days = [...]`. BTW, your tap gesture is always toggling the selected state of the first day in the array, is that what you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, as mentioned using a `struct Day` and `enumerated`
in the `ForEach` loop, and `@State private var days ...` as shown in the example code:

```
struct Day: Identifiable {  // <--- here
    let id = UUID()
    let value: Int
    var isSelected: Bool
    
    init(value: Int, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.value = value
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var days = [         // <--- here
        Day(value: 1, isSelected: true),
        Day(value: 2, isSelected: false),
        Day(value: 3, isSelected: false),
        Day(value: 4, isSelected: true)
    ]
    
    let layout = [
        GridItem(.fixed(40)),
        GridItem(.fixed(40)),
        GridItem(.fixed(40)),
        GridItem(.fixed(40))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: layout) {

                // --- here
                ForEach(Array(days.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, day in 
                    Capsule()
                        .overlay(Text("\(day.value)").foregroundColor(.white))
                        .foregroundColor(day.isSelected ? .blue : .red)
                        .frame(height: 40)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            days[index].isSelected.toggle()  // <--- here
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Or:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var days = [
        Day(value: 1, isSelected: true),
        Day(value: 2, isSelected: false),
        Day(value: 3, isSelected: false),
        Day(value: 4, isSelected: true)
    ]
    
    let layout = [
        GridItem(.fixed(40)),
        GridItem(.fixed(40)),
        GridItem(.fixed(40)),
        GridItem(.fixed(40))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: layout) {
                ForEach(days) { day in
                    Capsule()
                        .overlay(Text("\(day.value)").foregroundColor(.white))
                        .foregroundColor(day.isSelected ? .blue : .red)
                        .frame(height: 40)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if let index = days.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == day.id}) {
                                days[index].isSelected.toggle()  // <--- here
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```